# Office Js Api insertWorksheetsFromBase64 method Working on localhost and not working on publishing firebase/aws hosting

Tags: javascript, excel, flutter, office-js, office-addins

I am developing excel addin in flutter web. I have this function in project that is used to save current excel file and open new workbook and import sheets from my template file into that newly created file.

```
//save create and import
    function saveCreateAndImportWorkbookFromAssets() {
  // Path to your asset Excel file
  const filePath = 'assets/files/template.xlsx';

  // Firstly, save the current workbook
  Excel.run(function(context) {
    // Save the current workbook
    context.workbook.save(Excel.SaveBehavior.prompt);

    // Run the batch operation
    return context.sync()
      .then(function() {
        // Now that the workbook is saved, proceed to create a new workbook

        // Fetch the file
        return fetch(filePath);
      })
      .then(response => response.blob())
      .then(blob => {
        // Use FileReader to read the file as a data URL
        const reader = new FileReader();
        reader.onload = function(event) {
          // Extract the base64 string
          const base64Index = event.target.result.indexOf("base64,") + "base64,".length;
          const base64String = event.target.result.substring(base64Index);

          // Create a new workbook with the base64 string
          Excel.createWorkbook(base64String).then(function() {
            console.log("New workbook created and loaded with the sheets from the asset file.");
          }).catch(function(error) {
            console.error("Error creating new workbook:", error);
          });
        };

        // Read the fetched blob as a data URL
        reader.readAsDataURL(blob);
      })
      .catch(error => {
        console.error("Error fetching the asset Excel file:", error);
      });

  }).catch(function(error) {
    console.error("Error saving the current workbook:", error);
  });
};
```

This function works perfectly fine when i test this on my localhost but when i publish this to firebase it does not work
i have other feature related to office js library but all other things are working just fine. Means communication between my app and office js is working except this single function.

I am using this office js api method:
**https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/dev/add-ins/excel/excel-add-ins-workbooks#create-a-workbook**
I am side loading addin using this:
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/dev/add-ins/testing/create-a-network-shared-folder-catalog-for-task-pane-and-content-add-ins

i am trying to import excel sheet from a template using office js insertWorksheetsFromBase64 method its working in localhost:3000 port and failing on publishing to firebase/aws.

To replicate issue i have created a repo:
https://github.com/MalikSamiAwan/excel_addin_proof_of_concept

only need to do only following changes to make this work:
i have updated these two file i have customise package code according to my requirements files attached to the repo[https://github.com/MalikSamiAwan/excel_addin_proof_of_concept] inside this directory **updatedcustomfiletobereplaced**:
**file1 path:**
/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dev/officejs-0.4.0/lib/src/office_interops/**excel_js_impl.dart**
**file2 path:**
/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dev/officejs-0.4.0/lib/src/office/**excel.dart**

**Setup Local Addin:**

Addin Manifest file attached (filename: **sheetmanage_test1 copy.xml**) repo[https://github.com/MalikSamiAwan/excel_addin_proof_of_concept] inside this directory **updatedcustomfiletobereplaced**:

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/dev/add-ins/testing/create-a-network-shared-folder-catalog-for-task-pane-and-content-add-ins

Step1: For testing this feature in local host we need to side load this addin manifest: sheetmanage_test1.xml file attached
Step2: Start flutter web:
flutter run -d chrome --web-port 3000
And than we can replicate this issue[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bbq1A.png)

Answer (score 1):

The issue was due to file path. I have to place template file inside flutter web directory instead of assets directory.